# SQL Server Adventure Works Person.PersonPhone Table

Tags: sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I have a question about the Person.PersonPhone table in AdventureWorks2012, and a related question about SQL.

Firstly, in the table there is a phone number shown as 55-2555-0100, which appears to be a typo; presumably it was intended to be 552-555-0100, which would match the pattern of the other phone numbers. I was wondering if anyone could confirm that this is an error.

Secondly, suppose we want to determine which 3-digit US area codes do not appear in the PhoneNumber column.
One way to do this is to use the dbo.Nums table from Itzik Ben-Gan's TSQL2012 database, which has one column, n, containing the integers from 1 to 100,000. So, for example, the following query works:

(1)
    `SELECT n
    FROM dbo.Nums
    WHERE n >= 100 AND n < 1000 AND n NOT IN
           (SELECT SUBSTRING(P.PhoneNumber, 1, 3)
            FROM Person.PersonPhone AS P
            WHERE SUBSTRING(P.Phonenumber, 1, 3) LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9]');`

However, the following query fails:

(2)
    `SELECT n
    FROM dbo.Nums
    WHERE n >= 100 AND n < 1000 AND n NOT IN
           (SELECT SUBSTRING(P.PhoneNumber, 1, 3)
            FROM Person.PersonPhone AS P
            WHERE P.PhoneNumber LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9]%');`

The error is "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1 (' to data type int."

There are phone-numbers in the table of the form '1 (11) xxx', which should be ignored for the purposes of this exercise. Apparently it's trying to compare the n from dbo.Nums to these, even though the subquery excludes them. (The subquery in (2), when executed separately, has exactly the same result as the subquery in (1)).

Even stranger, if (2) is modified by doing something that has no effect (e.g. replace empty string with empty string in each PhoneNumber), the query suddenly works:

(3)
    `SELECT n
    FROM dbo.Nums
    WHERE n >= 100 AND n < 1000 AND n NOT IN
           (SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(P.PhoneNumber, '', ''), 1, 3)
            FROM Person.PersonPhone AS P
            WHERE P.PhoneNumber LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9]%');`

So why does (2) fail but (3) works?

Thanks,

Mark Brodie

Comment: My best guess is now its getting nulls as empty strings giving a larger not in match. Don't quote me and I don't have much to back it up... Switch the replace with a coalesce and see if you get the same behavior.... looks like potential data corruption if this query has been working.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the data may or may not be a typo, but it is a good sample and reminder to always program around potential data issues carefully.

As for (2) vs (3), the error is due to implicit conversions. In both (2) and (3), by using the `n NOT IN (<subquery>)`, you are implicitly forcing the elements returned by the subquery to be converted to an INT for the comparison, and the error message is that the elements from the subquery cannot all be converted to an INT (as is the case for your error message about phone numbers beginning with "1 (".

What is interesting is why (3) works but (2) does not. They would both work is you change `n NOT IN` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), n)`. Query (2) attempts this implicit conversion to INT for each element after the SUBSTRING but before the WHERE clause is applied, and this is what generates your error. In query (3), having the REPLACE first modifies the execution (and the execution plan confirms this) that the LIKE in the WHERE is applied before the implicit conversion to INT occurs on the result set.